# Trouble with autolayout constraints in OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, resize, autolayout, constraints

I just created a simple OS X project from default template (with `NSWindow`) and I want to add `UIImageView` and make it stretchable (when user changes the size of the window the image will be resized according to a new frame).

I added constraints - leading, trailing, top and bottom. But now it requests a concrete view width and height.

If I don't give it these extra constraints then the view became fullscreen. If I set these constraints then I am no longer able to resize the view/window. How to solve this issue?

Comment: are you adding `UIImageView` on `UIScrollView` ? If so then you'll need to give additional constraints to set content size of the scrollview.

Comment: I try to add a `UIImageView` to the `UIView` generated by xcode template and this view doesn't allow to set its size correctly